# how to make a rules by using Ant in a form?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ant-design-pro

I have a question about rules in a form.  Right now it shows the message `Please input your Username!` and `Username must be 26 letters of the alphabet(upper and lowercase) or Arabic number(0-9) or underscore(_) as a character`. When I type a space in username, I have already added whitespace: true in the rules, but it will still show both messages, so how could it only show `Please input your Username!` when I type space at the beginning in username?

```
import React from 'react';
import { Form, Input, Button } from 'antd';
import { UserOutlined, LockOutlined } from '@ant-design/icons';

import './login.less';
import logo from './images/logo.png';

const Item = Form.Item; //it must write after Import
const Login = () => {
  const onFinish = values => {
    console.log(values);
  };

  return (
    <div className="login">
      <header className="login-header">
        <img src={logo} alt="logo" />
        <h1>React Project: Backend Admin System</h1>
      </header>
      <section className="login-content">
        <h3>User Login</h3>
        <Form onFinish={onFinish} name="normal_login" className="login-form">
          <Item
            name="username"
            rules={[
              { required: true, whitespace:true, message: 'Please input your Username!' },
              {
                min: 4,
                message: 'username must be at least 4 characters',
              },
              {
                max: 12,
                message: 'username cannot be longer than 12 characters',
              },
              {
                pattern: /^[a-zA-Z0-9_]+$/,
                message:
                  'Username must be 26 letters of the alphabet(upper and lowercase) or Arabic number(0-9) or underscore(_) as a character',
              },
            ]}
          >
            <Input
              prefix={
                <UserOutlined
                  className="site-form-item-icon"
                  style={{ color: 'rgba(0,0,0,.25) ' }}
                />
              }
              placeholder="Username"
            />
          </Item>
          <Item name="password">
            <Input
              prefix={
                <LockOutlined
                  className="site-form-item-icon"
                  style={{ color: 'rgba(0,0,0,.25) ' }}
                />
              }
              type="password"
              placeholder="Password"
            />
          </Item>
          <Item>
            <Button type="primary" htmlType="submit" className="login-form-button">
              Log in
            </Button>
          </Item>
        </Form>
      </section>
    </div>
  );
};
export default Login;
```

Comment: Just remove the `whitespace: true` on your 1st rule. You just overthink on it. The user will still not complete the registration if the user enter space at the beginning because it will not meet the pattern. The only goal is to complete the registration without errors.

Comment: Thanks man :) Ant v3 can exist both rules that will show the message when user enter space at the beginning, but  v4 can not do it., because i saw a tuition video with v3. just being curious to ask about this question.